# Is it possible load in trasparent way for the user a cross reference file declaration in xtext web editor?

Tags: web, xtext, ace-editor, cross-reference

I'm building integration of text editors in web applications using Xtext. I chose ace as an editor, following [this](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/330_web_support.html) documentation. Is it possible to hide or load a cross-reference declaration file in a transparent way for the user?

The actual editor shows:

```
Integers: int a, int b, int sum //cross reference declaration loaded from a file

sum = s + a;
```

I want only the second line in the editor without obtaining a reference error.

Comment: am not sure if i get your question. Xtext sees and allows referencing independ of the location for all files i a project. or is this about a libary? then if the model is a java project having the lib in a jar works too. or is that about a libary compltly in code

Comment: @ChristianDietrich thanks for the reply. When do I use web integration how does it work? Where should I save the file for cross reference in the project? Because when I run ace editor if I don't write the first line I get the reference error.

Comment: In Web you will the ResourceSet yourself anyway so do it when you create it